# Why does the Hudson Integration Game plugin does not work after update?

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson

Recently I updated the [cigame-plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/The+Continuous+Integration+Game+plugin) for Hudson to version 1.12. Now I recognized, that no build get points at the moment. The builds are SCM-triggered and the CI-game is activated for the project and the user. What is going wrong? How can I fix it?

**EDIT**: I have to correct, the update to the new version of the plugin isn't the problem. Looking through the build-history I can see, that after this update builds got a score. But at some point the builds are not longer scored. Nothing happened to hudson at this time, no restart, no reconfiguration etc. Simply SCM-changes came in and triggered builds.

**EDIT 2**: The ci-game-plugin counts a score for builds started manually, but not for builds started by changes in version-control. I have no idea why it behaves this way.

**EDIT 3**: Further investigation shows that I have [this bug](https://hudson.dev.java.net/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=3726) with the same stacktrace produced.

Answer (score 0):

This is so specific to the current state of the Hudson plugin ecosystem, I suggest you go directly to the [users mailing list](http://www.nabble.com/Hudson-users-f16872.html) with the question, where the plugin developers can help you directly.